# SBT 0.11 InputKey depending on other tasks

Tags: scala, sbt

In `0.7.x` we used `dependsOn` to declare that a task depends on other tasks - meaning other tasks have to be executed first.

In `0.11.x` we use `<<=` to declare that a task depends on some other task. The SBT wiki says a lot on how to declare a `TaskKey[_]` which depends on other tasks and settings (there are questions here that deal with [that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7400849/how-to-depend-on-other-tasks-and-do-your-code-in-sbt-0-10)), but not much on `InputKey[_]`. If I have an input key declared like this:

```
val benchTask = InputKey[Unit](
  "bench",
  "Runs a specified benchmark."
) <<= inputTask {
  (argTask: TaskKey[Seq[String]]) =>
  argTask map {
    args =>
    // ...
  } // xxx
}
```

How can I make it depend on other tasks, like for example `packageBin in Test`? I can put `dependsOn` instead of the `xxx` comment above, but that gives me type errors.

Thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Map your other task together with argTask:

```
inputTask {
  (argTask: TaskKey[Seq[String]]) =>
  (argTask, packageBin in Test) map {
    (args, pb) =>
    // ...
  }
}
```

Comment: Does that mean that I have to have the argument `pb` for `packageBin` in the `map`, even though I'm not interested in its value, just the dependency?

Comment: Yes, you are interested in a previous value to depend on.

Comment: How does the answer snippet relate to the question snippet? Does it just replace from "inputTask {" on line 4?

Comment: Yes, sure. Sorry that this was not obvious from my answer.