# Make compile action in an SBT subproject depend on compilation of other subprojects without adding them to classpath

Tags: scala, sbt

For certain reasons I want to make compilation of a subproject `a` require compilation of `b` *without* `b` appearing in `a`'s classpath. Instead, `a` classes will be accessed by loading them dynamically (yes, this is generally speaking a bad idea, but it is a requirement). This question was asked before for previous SBT versions, e.g. [How to depend on other tasks and do your code in SBT 0.10?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7400849/how-to-depend-on-other-tasks-and-do-your-code-in-sbt-0-10?rq=1). 
I've tried

```
(compile in (a, Compile)) <<= (compile in (b, Compile), compile in (a, Compile)) {
  (_, out) => out
}
```

(based on the above answer) and

```
(compile in (a, Compile)) := {
  (compile in (b, Compile)).value
  (compile in (a, Compile)).value
}
```

Neither appears to work in SBT 0.13.9.

Comment: Both ways you posted should work just fine

Comment: Try this: `lazy val a = Project(...).settings(compile in Compile <<= compile in Compile dependsOn (compile in Compile in b)).aggregate(b);`. I'm not sure you need `aggregate` here, try both.

Comment: @yahor Yes, this works (without aggregate). Please make this an answer so I can accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `dependsOn` operator to override the default `compile` behavior in the  settings of module `a`.

```
lazy val a = Project(...)
    .settings(compile in Compile <<= compile in Compile dependsOn (compile in Compile in b))
```

Comment: This solution relies on deprecated code and will result in the message: warning: `<<=` operator is deprecated. Use `key := { x.value }` or `key ~= (old => { newValue })`.